# Is it possible to partition cache size to different cores in Linux?

Tags: cache

I have a Ivybridge processor running Ubuntu. The processor has four cores sharing the same last level (L3) cache. I believe the cache is shared on demand due to Intel Smartcache technology.

Can I configure the cache to be strictly partitioned to be used by different cores?

Comment: I don't think that is possible and I don't see any benefit in doing so.

Comment: @DanD. You are right. I don't see any benefit also except for my purpose-----research........